# intersection of two or more lists of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have

```
l1 = [{"value": 1, "label": "One"}, {"value": 2, "label": "Two"}]
l2 = [{"value": 1, "label": "One"}, {"value": 2, "label": "Two"}]
l3 = [{"value": 1, "label": "One"}, {"value": 3, "label": "Three"}]
l4 = [{"value": 4, "label": "Four"}]
```

and I need something like this:

```
def foo(*lists):
    ...
```

that returns:

```
foo(l1, l2) -> [{"value": 1, "label": "One"}, {"value": 2, "label": "Two"}] 
foo(l2, l3) -> [{"value": 1, "label": "One"}]
foo(l1, l2, l3) -> [{"value": 1, "label": "One"}]
foo(l1, l2, l3, l4) -> []
```

**Edit** (sorry I truncated part of the question):
The order in the output list doesn't matter.

I tried to use the sets but the dicts inside the lists are unhashable.
So I tried to transform dicts in frozendict or tuple but the keys order in input dict should not be significant:

```
{"value": 1, "label": "One"} == {"label": "One", "value": 1}

l5 = [{"value": 1, "label": "One"}]
l6 = [{"label": "One", "value": 1}]
foo(l5, l6) -> [{"value": 1, "label": "One"}]
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Does the order matter? What would the output of `foo([{'x': 1}], [{}, {'x': 1}])` be?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Read [ask].

Comment: @Aran-Fey the output would be [{"x":1}]

Comment: @Sayse sorry. Now I edited the original quest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the list of dicts to set of tuples of dict items so that you can use `functools.reduce` to perform `set.intersection` on all the sets, and then convert the resulting sequence of sets to a list of dicts by mapping the sequence to the dict constructor:

```
from functools import reduce
def intersection(*lists):
    return list(map(dict, reduce(set.intersection, ({tuple(d.items()) for d in l} for l in lists))))
```

so that with your sample input:

```
print(intersection(l1, l2))
print(intersection(l2, l3))
print(intersection(l1, l2, l3))
print(intersection(l1, l2, l3, l4))
```

would output:

```
[{'value': 1, 'label': 'One'}, {'value': 2, 'label': 'Two'}]
[{'value': 1, 'label': 'One'}]
[{'value': 1, 'label': 'One'}]
[]
```